# Maximum size of canvas element

Tags: html, css, canvas

I tried to search but I didn't found suitable answer.
I want to create Canvas that users can draw on it.
But from what I read before there is no option to set canvas size in percent.
So I need to give it fixed value in `px`, so my question is:

Which width size will suite to all resulution without scrolling horzintally ?

Comment: You need to use media queries to make it responsive. There isn't a one size fits all because a screen could be any sort of size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the users who are going to use the canvas and what it is going to be used for. I would recommend the following:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
    .myCanvas{
        width:300px;
        height:533px;
    }
}
/*Large phone Size*/
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .myCanvas{
        width:600px;
        height: 1066px;
    }
}
/*Tablet and Standard Size*/
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
        .myCanvas{
        width:1920px;
        height:1080px;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code won't work (which is a bummer) as the width and height need to be defined in the HTML tag, however you can still use these sizes for scaling purposes depending on who you're designing the canvas for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it in Java Script to change the size of the canvas